# Backup and Restore SSP on MOSS 2007 fails due to missing .mdf files

Tags: sharepoint, moss, backup, restore

I've used the central admin backup facility to backup our Shared Services Provider. The backup location was a drive on a new server.

I then try to restore the SSP via central admin on the new server. It fails with an error relating to the fact that it cant find the .mdf files that it requires. It is looking in the location that they were on the original server.

Does the backup not take care of moving these .mdf files as part of the backup restore process?

Would appreciate anyone's suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you following [these instructions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc896556.aspx) on migrating the SSP?

Comment: I was actually using the backup/restore tools in central admin as I had tried the above method and ran into issues with it. Does moving the SSP using those instructions require me to move the database's manually?

Comment: I have never hear of anyone using the central admin backup and restore. I don't even know if it works or in what situations you would use it.